# Almost-Cantor Set Example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, cantor-set

I'm in a Facebook group about sharing false "theorems" and one of them was the following:

> Let X be a compact, metrizable and totally disconnected, then X is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

I can come up with plenty of counter examples, but none with the same cardinality as the Cantor set. I've tried things like $C\times\{0,1\}$ for example, but that's still homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Can you provide an example of a set that satisfies the hypothesis of the "theorem," is of the same cardinality as the cantor set, but isn't homeomorphic to it?

Comment: I'm glad to know that some people use Facebook for this ! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cantor set has no isolated points, so add one. The result is still compact, metrizable, and totally disconnected.

Comment: Oh, right. I considered that and dismissed it on the grounds that the set wouldn't be perfect... which isn't one of the conditions.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I don't know if there's a *perfect* counterexample off the top of my head, but I suspect not - incidentally, you get a near-miss argument by showing that every compact metric space is a continuous image of Cantor space, and that every perfect subset of Cantor space is homeomorphic to the whole.

Comment: Any compact, perfect, totally disconnected metric space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set (in some contexts this is taken as the definition of a Cantor set), so there isn't a counterexample that's also perfect.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Ah yes I missed the obvious homeomorphism, what I get for trying to do math while rushing out the door.